Formatting in Millions - MS Access
I'm trying to format a figure in an access form to read in millions but retain the 0. in how it displays.
Using the formatting: #,###,,.0 makes my figure of 200,000 read as .2 which is great.... But I need it to show as 0.2
The data coming from the query is definitely fine as if I remove the formatting altogether and set the value as 0 it displays 0.00
I've also tried making small adjustments to the format but with no luck.
Is there a tweak to the format above or a revised one which will set me straight?
Many thanks

Use the format #,##0.0. Note that it automatically expands to millions or billions. You don't have to specify additional ,s. You can even write only #,0.0.
